# Can't update to webpack 3.10.0

Tags: webpack

I tried to update webpack 1.13 to 3.10.0 using

```
npm update -g webpack --save
```

After the update when I check the version using

```
npm webpack --version
```

I get `3.10.8`

But when I check the package.json it shows

```
"webpack": "^1.15.0"
```

Can someone please help me with this issue. How can I update it to 3.10.0?

Answer (score 1):

`npm update -g webpack --save` command update only the global `webpack` package.

To update your local install version of the webpack, run this command in your project root folder.

`npm install webpack --save`

Comment: I did. The package.json still says 1.15.0

Comment: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN myproject@28.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN myproject@28.0.0 license should be a valid SPDX license expression

Comment: In your project root folder, delete the `package-lock.json` file. and try installing webpack `npm install webpack@latest --save`

Answer (score -1):

Try using yarn instead of npm. It's way faster and handles dependency version correctly.

For above problem, try deleting webpack from your `package.json` and reinstall again.